# build and run with xcodebuild (osx)

Tags: macos, xcodebuild

I am trying to figure out how to build and run in one pass, using xcodebuild.

At the moment, I just get the target build; but I can't find a way to actually execute the same sequence that you get from xcode, when you push the play button(build&run).

All the documentation that I did find, was mostly for iOS, so once you set the destination, magic happens and the build goes on the device, and run.
Although this does not work with an OSX target. This is what I am running:

```
xcodebuild -target testapp -project testapp.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -destination platform=OSX
```

Comment: Same question, no answer though; he did wrote a script, I want to understand how it works. If I have to call the executable via bash, I had the solution already :)

Comment: It's possible using a scheme or post installation script, and there's also `-xctestrun` which might not be what you are looking for... (it can't really be used with the `-project` or `-workspace` parameters).